# Perl LibXML: When using load_xml ... is there an equivalent close_xml feature?

Tags: perl, libxml2

When I use "load_xml" in a foreach loop, is there a need or an equivalent "close" cmd that I should be using?  I 've been googling/looking, but I haven't found one.

Sort of same concern with the line marked "<-- HERE too" ?  I'm creating a "new" schema each time.  Don't I have to be concerned I'm creating these 'new' or 'loading' instances but I'm not closing them?

Note: Each xml_file is different and thus has a different xsd file, hence reason for loop.

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new({keep_blanks=>(0)});    
foreach my $xml_file (@xml_file_list)
{
 my $dom = $parser->load_xml(location => $xml_file) or die;
 my $schema_file = $xsd_path."/".$xsd_file;
 my $schema = XML::LibXML::Schema->new(location => $schema_file); #<--HERE too

 eval { $schema->validate($dom)};
 if ($@)
 {
  print "File failed validation: $@\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$dom is declared with `my`. Therefore, once the variable goes out of scope, the object is destroyed (unless there is a reference to it).

You can even try `undef $dom` if you want to get rid of the object before the end of scope.

Comment: Sorry: yes I agree with the 1st part of my original question. So what you are saying is that since $dom is declared with "my", each subsequent loop iteration is in effect redefining the previous one ... I can buy that.  

But what about the "my $schema" line - I guess what's throwing me off is the use/term of method "new" - I'm concern that the very meaning of "new" is that it's creating multiple versions of $schema under the hood ... would this be true or is not a problem?

Comment: @CraigP: It behaves the same. It is created for each iteration of the loop, at the end of the loop, its scope ends and the object is destroyed.

Comment: btw - I didn't want to start a 2nd thread just for this observation/issue: With the above validation code, it does not print-out the error line numbers. Would anybody know how to resolve this? I might have to go the xmllint or xmlstarlet way instead - I already know they work.